# C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++, boost, split, compiler-errors

I am currently working on Advent of Code day 2 and I am trying out some different stuff for the first time. I heard about boost split through a podcast while on the road and immediately wanted to give it a go when I got home.

I have my vector games as the output, the input gameSets, and the delimiter ;.
I was hoping to print each element within games to the console to ensure my elements were correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>

vector<std::string> games;

void partOneAnswer() {

    // Open File
    std::string filePath = "test_values.txt";
    std::ifstream stream(filePath);
    std::string line;

    if (stream.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(stream, line)) {

            // printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
            std::string delimiter = ":";
            std::string gameSets = line.substr(line.find(delimiter) + 2, line.length());
            //printf("%s\n", gameSets.c_str());

            while (gameSets != "") {
                // place each set into a vector, being delimited by ;
                boost::split(games, gameSets, ";");
                for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << games[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result was the error.
Any ideas on why?

Error takes me to:

```
\boost\algorithm\string\detail\finder.hpp 578
```

Compiling was not an issue until I added boost.

Comment: What line does the error refer to? What is the full copy/pasted error message? I get a different error because `games` doesn't exist in this code. https://godbolt.org/z/xfb1Eb9aE

Comment: sorry I don't know why I didn't add it, I try to avoid coming to forums with my issues too often lol. 


Error C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments AOC23_Cube_Conundrum  \boost\algorithm\string\detail\finder.hpp 578  

it takes me to line 578 of finder.hpp

also I forgot to add in my vector variable, Ill update the code to reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[boost::split](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id-1.3.3.5.9) needs a predicate for its delimiter, you can't use a string:

```
boost::split(games, gameSets, boost::is_any_of(";"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed! You sir are a magician.